# python SharedMemory persistence between processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Is there any way to make `SharedMemory` object created in Python persist between processes?

If the following code is invoked in interactive python session:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import shared_memory
>>> shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='test_smm', size=1000000, create=True)
```

it creates a file in `/dev/shm/` on a Linux machine.

```
ls /dev/shm/test_smm 
/dev/shm/test_smm
```

But when the python session ends I get the following:

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d
```

and the `test_smm` is gone:

```
ls /dev/shm/test_smm 
ls: cannot access '/dev/shm/test_smm': No such file or directory
```

So is there any way to make the shared memory object created in python persist across process runs?

Running with Python 3.8

Comment: Can you just dump state to a file when your program exits, and load that state when your other process starts up?

Comment: I cannot.  The process will write continuously and there is another process that is reading it.  So if there is any issue and process crashes or exits I need the memory to persist.  I can do this if I use `sysv_ipc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can unregister a shared memory object from the resource cleanup process without unlinking it:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.6 (default, Sep 25 2020, 09:36:53) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import shared_memory, resource_tracker
>>> shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='test_smm', size=1000000, create=True)
>>> resource_tracker.unregister(shm._name, 'shared_memory')
>>> 
$ ls /dev/shm/test_smm 
/dev/shm/test_smm
```

I don't know whether this is portable, and it doesn't look like a supported way of using the multiprocessing module, but it works on Linux at least.

Comment: You're right this seems to be the only way to do it now but there is an issue tracker for Python to resolve this:

https://bugs.python.org/issue38119

Comment: @Diego Veralli how did you discover this module? It seems there is no documentation in docs.python.org for resource_tracker.

Comment: @andreihondrari I had a quick look at the source code for the `shared_memory` module.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html): "When one process no longer needs access to a shared memory block that might still be needed by other processes, the `close()` method should be called." So maybe add `shm.close()` for completeness?